# Grab formula from anther worksheet base on value in heading

Tags: vba, excel

I hope I named the question correctly

I now have two tables: table A to store the formula I want, and table B to be filled. I want to copy the formula (not value) from table A to table B row 2 base on the heading in table B row 1.

Here's the code I have

```
Sub test()

Dim codearea As Range
Dim code

Set codearea = Worksheets("Table B").Range("B2:K2")
For Each code In codearea
If Cells(1, code.Column).Value = "Formula1" Then
Worksheets("Table A").Range("A1").Copy
Cells(code.Row, code.Column).Paste
End If
Next code

End Sub
```

It keep telling me that the formula lookup to Table A is out of range.
I want to save the formula in Table A instead of directly type them in the Macro, just to more flexibility.
Any idea?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the formulas directly.

```
Worksheets("Table B").Range("B2:K2").Formula = Worksheets("Table A").Range("A1").Formula
```

Comment: It still tell me 'out of range'. I don't know if there's anything to do with the code range I set up.

Comment: I don't know how to link a workbook here. Error given is 'subscript out of range' with line: 'Worksheets("Table A").Range("A1").Copy'

Comment: No worry, I figure it out! Thanks!